# Почему таблица "выскакивает" из дива?

Tags: html

Есть [страничка](http://dokazi.ru/shablo.php). По коду таблица с id=main должна содержать все эти div'ы, однако в браузере все таблицы выпадают в конец.

```
   <?php
session_start();
echo '
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Докажи.РУ</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="aj.js"></script>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
<table id="top">
<tr><td>
<div id="userst">';
include('inc1.php');
$log = $_GET['log'];
if($log==1){
session_destroy();
header("Refresh: 0;URL='http://dokazi.ru/'");
}
echo '
</div>
 </td></tr>
</table>
 <table id="maint">
<tr><div id ="toper"></div></tr>
<tr><div  id="center">
<div id="usloviye">
<table id="of" border="1">
<tr><td colspan="2">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>lol</td>
<td>lol</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="plus"></div>
<div id="minus"></div>
    </div></tr>
<tr><div  id="foot"></div></tr>
 </table>
 ';
include('inc3.php');
echo '
    </body>
</html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В-третьих: комментарии офомляются как <!-- -->

Во-вторых: последовательность <table><tr><td></td></tr></table> обязательна. "потерять" <td> - нельзя. Кусок исправленного кода см. ниже.

Во-первых - так не верстают. Если вы используете div - то их не нужно заключать в таблицу (тем более так). Столбиком (один под-другим) они выстроятся без всяких усилий))

Если вы ЗНАЕТЕ и ПОНИМАЕТЕ как верстать таблицами - делайте таблицами. Это как бы считается "не круто", но никто ж не сказал, что нельзя.

```
<table id="maint">
<tr>    
<td><div id ="toper"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div  id="center">
        <!-- здесь начинается место для формулировки цвет ffcc00 -->
    <div id="usloviye">
    <table id="of" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>lol</td>
        <td>lol</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        <!-- здесь оканчивается место для формулировки цвет ffcc00 !-->
        <!-- доква цвет ? зеленоватый !-->
    <div id="plus"></div>
        <!-- конец доква -->
        <!-- опров цвет ? розоватый -->
    <div id="minus"></div>
        <!-- конец опров -->
    </div>
</td>

</tr>
<tr><td><div  id="foot"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```